# Apache Beam HTTP Unbounded Source Python

Tags: python, http, apache-beam, apache-beam-io, apache-beam-kafkaio

Is it possible with the current version of Apache Beam to develop an unbounded source that receives data in a HTTP message?
My intention is to run an HTTP Server and to inject the messages received into a Beam Pipeline. If it is possible, can it be done with the existing sources?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. you can develop it by leveraging [Splittable DoFn](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#splittable-dofns). [Source](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/developing-io-java/) looks like they are going to be depreciated in the near future.

From my end, I am trying to develop such a pipeline that would consume a Rest API that is streaming Json messages in the get's body and supports multiple connections, hence splitting the workload on API side like [Adobe Livestream](https://github.com/AdobeDocs/analytics-1.4-apis/blob/master/docs/live-stream-api/getting_started.md#) or [Twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/consuming-streaming-data). This behaviour should enable scaling on the consumer end (Dataflow)

My struggle is that i can't figure out a splittable restriction out of this use case. The streaming is infinite and there is no Offset like in messaging brokers like Kafka or bytes range (files). I wanted first to build element restriction pairs like: (url,buffered reader) but i don't think buffered readers can be split.

[image]

One of the solutions might be not to provide a restriction at all. I am struggling to imagine how the pipeline would distribute elements hence scale.